# React Native adds data when button is push

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and I am new to javascript. I have a problem with my code that i can't seem to find where the error is.

My app has a user that can add and save plate numbers. The problem is everytime I save the plate or click the add button or just plainly click the plates that are already saved, it duplicates itself

Here is my code for this one

```
export default class plakaco extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            plates: [
                {plateNumber: '', status: '', id: 1},


            ]
        }
        this.getPlateId = this.getPlateId.bind(this);
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        let newArr = this.state.plates.slice(0);
        let idPlate =  this.state.plates[this.state.plates.length - 1];
        let newId = idPlate.id + 1
        newArr.push({plateNumber: nextProps.pn, status: 'Saved', id: newId})
        this.setState({
            plates: newArr
        })
    }
     componentDidMount() {
        AsyncStorage.getItem("id").then(val => {
            this.setState({
              "id": val
            })
            fetch(`http://aaa.com/api/getClientPlates/${val}`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({})
            }).then(response => {
                response.json().then(data => {
                    console.log(data)
                })
            })
        }).done()
    }
  getPlateId(i, plateNumber, inputEditable){
        this.props.getValues(plateNumber, inputEditable, false, false);
  }

    addAPlate(){
        this.props.getValues('', true, true, true);
    }

  render() {
    return (
            <View style={styles.leftView}>
                <Button
                    onPress={this.addAPlate.bind(this)} 
                    title="ADD"
                    color="#343434"
                    accessibilityLabel="Add a plate."
                />
                <PlateItems plates={this.state.plates} getPlateId={this.getPlateId}/>
            </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  leftView: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#F1F1F1'
  }
});
```

[Here is a sample image of no plates added or saved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmlHD.jpg)

[Sample Image with save plates that duplicates itself whenever it is click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJtD7.jpg)

Thank you so much!

Comment: why you are using ```this.props.getValues```

Comment: generally, you want to call async fetch once a button is clicked such as ```getItem```

Comment: why you need 
```
 this.setState({
              "id": val
            })
``` even before getting data from API data?

Comment: My friend coded this one and i have to continue this project, I dont know why he put that in there

Comment: do you want to append new plate on button click which will get data from API?

Comment: tested compontWillRecieveProps is working fine as expected but it never got invoked so it's not contributing to duplicate list.
https://jsbin.com/yepitejeno/2/edit?js,output

Comment: No sir, i want everytime i click a plate it will not add a new one

Comment: Kinda lost here, this is my first time in js